# Read specific part from string via MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a varchar field that contains a description with variable lenght. I want to read the third part from the left (which is written inbetween the second and third _ from the left).

For example if the table contained:

```
|col1 |
+-----+
|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE |
|20161512_CR_Premium_2_DE |
|20161512_SV_SDT_4_DE|
```

Expected Outcome:

```
|col1 |
+-----+
|Luxus|
|Premium|
|SDT|
```

How can I do this?

Thanks for your support!

Tried it already like this, but I think this is not correct...

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(`col1`, '_', 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not be efficient but, given your specific requirement you could do this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`col1`, '_', -3),'_', 1) from `table`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should nest these functions like so

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX("20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE","_",-3),"_",1)

Luxus
```